# After an "adb reboot" how to check some other events are complete before the device is ready

Tags: android, adb

I am running automated testing on Android device connected to my laptop over USB.
My script starts with two "**adb shell**" commands before it runs the test as below:

```
    ::Hey device, wakeup and open the home screen
    adb shell input keyevent 26
    adb shell input touchscreen swipe 240 480 480 640 100
    ...
    (here starts the test cases)
```

Now, I would like to add "**adb reboot**" at the very beginning of the script so that my device reboots and starts clean. But the issue is after reboot my device goes following sequences before becoming ready:

1. Device reboot
2. Starts connecting to the MDM server (Mobile Device Manager)
3. While connecting screen plays an progress animation
4. After successfully connected to the MDM, device become ready

I have tried:

```
adb reboot
adb wait-for-device shell input keyevent 26
```

But my problem is that **adb wait-for-device shell input keyevent 26** runs right after reboot (sequence #1 above) and after going thru sequences #2,3 & 4, my script does nothing.

How can I check that sequences 2,3 & 4 are complete ?

Comment: One thing you could do is configure an activity to start from a boot receiver, and then check `ps` to see if it is running.

Comment: Hello Alex P., I have edited my question with more information, but I don't know how to remove the 'DUPLICATE' tag on that, I hope, you can remove this.

Comment: Some of the ideas found at the linked question should still apply, you'd just need to identify something having to do with the events you want to wait for.